# Get two array from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects:

```
const dataset = [
  {name: 'Marie', year: 12, country: 'Canada'},
  {name: 'Jeff', year: 18, country: 'France'},
  {name: 'Joss', year: 10, country: 'Spain'},
  {name: 'Carrie', year: 45, country: 'Belgium'},
  {name: 'Linda', year: 32, country: 'France'},
]
```

I want two array: one with names and one with countries:

```
const names = ['Marie', 'Jeff', 'Joss', 'Carrie', 'Linda']
const countries = ['Canada', 'France', 'Spain', 'Belgium', 'France']
```

So, I usually do:

```
const names = dataset.map(e => e.name)
const countries = dataset.map(e => e.country)
```

Is there a simplest way possibly using a single loop?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is any simpler but it does use only a single loop:

```
 const dataset={ ... }
 const names=[], countries=[]
 for (var d of dataset) { 
     names.push(d.name); 
     countries.push(d.country);
 }
```

Surprisingly, according to jsben.ch, this approach is [about 6 times faster](http://jsben.ch/HK73E) than running `map` twice.

Comment: You can get about another 20% performance increase if you pre-allocate the array length and use destructuring to reduce the property lookup time. `const names = new Array(dataset.length), countries = new Array(dataset.length); var idx = 0; for(const {name, country} of dataset) { names[idx] = name; countries[idx++] = country }`

Comment: @Blindman67 that is good info.  Do you know why `map` is so much slower?

Comment: Iterating the dataset twice. The overhead of a new context each time the callback is called, though you only use the first argument, the callback is passed three, and there is the preliminary, vetting and setup when map is called. You will find that map does better (improves not better than)  in comparison when the array length is longer.

Comment: That test tells me that map is almost twice as fast. With Blindman67's improvements they are about the same.

Comment: I was testing in Firefox.  In Chrome I see what you see and map is faster there.